# Ingesting Elastic output into Elastic

Tags: json, elasticsearch, data-ingestion

I have a customer that provided me with the output of an Elastic query that looks like the following, in a JSON file:

```
    {
    "took": 74,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 169905,
        "max_score": 1,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "myindex",
                "_type": "data",
                "_id": "46c40732-71b6-4d30-96de-d38d6fc88b6786c7b6e758a4e927a8beb906a52cfc47d00f58bb472fc031fadac042591d7400",
                "_score": 1,
                "_source": {
                    "reqSize": 0,
...
                   "respCode": 0
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "myindex",
                "_type": "data",
                "_id": "46c40732-71b6-4d30-96de-d38d6fc88b67f3edcdcee2f1710aac0325ecfc190addcfdb842f3efa3ce391306c9ca2eaf628",
                "_score": 1,
                "_source": {
                    "reqSize": 0,
...
                   "respCode": 0
                }
            }, ...
```

As one can see, there are almost 170.000 records. 
I would like to ingest this data in my test Elastic. The data I need to ingest is what is in _source. How best can I extract this from the file? Is logstash the right tool for doing that, provided that the input is in a JSON file?

Thanks for your suggestions.
C

Comment: yes, logstash and codec json

Comment: What do you want to do? if you want to duplicate index - you should use over tools (_reindex...) / snapshot.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option to take data from one Elasticsearch cluster to another is to make a [snapshot](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-snapshots.html) on the source cluster. Archive the files and restore them on target. Just check that both clusters have the same version.